# Getting error: javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error getting property '0' from bean of type java.lang.Boolean

Tags: runtime-error, render, xpages-ssjs

I am getting the following error while setting the render property of a panel to true. I researched a lot but could not find anything online:

javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error getting property '0' from bean of type java.lang.Boolean Error getting property '0' from bean of type java.lang.Boolean

Following is the code for the render property of the panel:

```
if(viewScope.curApprCycle != "2"){
return true;
}
if(viewScope.curApprStatus.equals("2")){
if(viewScope.isUserAppraiser){
    return true;
}
}
if(viewScope.curApprStatus.equals("3")){
return true;
}
return false;
```

The error is encountered when the code enters the first if condition and returns true. The strange thing is if I return false instead of true in the if condition the error is not encountered. Not only this but even if I completely remove the render property calculation and set the visible check box ticked it still gives the same error. Just to add, this panel is within a dojo tab container within one of the tab pane.

Comment: You say: "if I completely remove the render property calculation and set the visible check box ticked it still gives the same error.". Then the error is most likely not related to the render property of the panel.

Comment: Yup you are right. I think its something to do with the repeat control that I am using inside the panel. I added another panel and tried the same code on the render property and it worked fine, but when I added the repeat control to it I started getting the same error.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. It may sound silly but the repeat control was not configured to get values in a particular condition. I am using a repeat bound to multi-value fields on the backend form. In the if condition about the repeat was not configured to any value because of which when the panel was set to render it was throwing the above error.